# Lentidão JSF após implementar PhaseListener

Tags: jsf-2.2

Estou implementando a interface PhaseListener e agora o sistema ficou lento. Estive fazendo uma análise e vi que o JSF está realizando repetidas chamadas para uma página que possui apenas um painel com informações vindas do banco de dados. Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo ou já passou por esse problema antes? É possível diminuir a quantidade de chamadas? Alguma dica?

Obs.: Na implementação dos métodos da PhaseListener coloquei apenas um System.out.println("") então a lentidão não é causada por nenhum código implementado neles.

Antes da fase: RESTORE_VIEW 1

Depois da fase: RESTORE_VIEW 1

Depois da fase: RESTORE_VIEW 1

Antes da fase: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

Antes da fase: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

Depois da fase: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

Depois da fase: APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

Antes da fase: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

Antes da fase: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

Depois da fase: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

Depois da fase: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

Antes da fase: UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

Antes da fase: UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

Depois da fase: UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

Depois da fase: UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

Antes da fase: INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

Antes da fase: INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

Depois da fase: INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

Depois da fase: INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

Antes da fase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Antes da fase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Comment: na sua página tente colocar isso e veja se funciona:
`<f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="dummy" />
  </f:metadata>`

Comment: Já havia colocado isso, vlw pelo comentário

Comment: @LucasVinícius, mostre como está escrito seu arquivos `faces-config.xml` e o `web.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Já passei exatamente por esse problema. Isto é causado pela configuração do seu arquivo `web.xml`, onde você deverá apagar as linhas a seguir:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```